# Two dropdown date picker instead one

Tags: jquery, date, duplicates, picker

I have a datepicker input ,and the problem is on input click appear two dropdowns instead one.
That's appear just at the first click.If you click outside the input and again in input it will show properly(just 1 dropdown table).

Example www.kilometri.ro/brasovtour/bvtour (click on schimba data).

the html

```
 <div class="modal-body">
       <input id="id-date-picker-1 change_date" class="span10 date-picker" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"></input>
     </div>
```

the javascript

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker();
```

EDIT:

I search in code with inspect element and I found a div with class "datepicker-inline" that have an inline css (display: block) and I rewrite in my css with `display :block` and now appear just 1 dropdown

Comment: nothing is happened,when we click on (schimba data).

Answer (score 0):

Check This :

```
 $(function() {
    $('#id-date-picker-1').datepicker();
    });
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/9fevXoeX0pbwUaEE0dfJ?p=preview